# Why does flex resource tag not support localization?

Tags: apache-flex, localization

Some places in my flex app, I use ResourceManager.getInstance().getString, and other places I use mxml @Resource tag to retrieve resource properties dynamically loaded from ResourceManager.

`resourceManager.loadResourceModule(resourceModuleURL);`

But only strings from ResourceManager.getInstance().getString show proper locale based values, while the @Resource tag only returns values from en_US resource. I guess it is because en_US is what I compiled with (-locale=en_US ).

So I am wondering if I am using a dynamicly-loaded resource, do I have to abandon the @Resource tag and use ResourceManager.getInstance().getString ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compile, you need to include a list of comma-separated locales:

`-locale=en_US,es_ES`

That should allow @Resource to then be used for localization.

More detail in the help documentation:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f3a.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf6119c-7fef

Excerpt:

> To be able to change the locale at run time without using resource
>   modules, you compile all the available locales into the application at
>   compile time by including them as part of the locale option. This
>   compiler option takes a comma-separated list of locales. If you add a
>   second locale, such as es_ES, change the locale option to the
>   following:

`-locale=en_US,es_ES`

**EDIT:**

To separate the locales into separate SWF files, try creating Resource Modules. Here's an excerpt:

> Resource modules are SWF files, separate from your application SWF
>   file, that contain resources bundles for a single locale. Your
>   application can preload one or more resource modules as it starts up,
>   before it displays its user interface. It can also load resource
>   modules later, such as in response to the user selecting a new locale.
>   The ResourceManager interacts with all resource bundles the same,
>   whether the bundles it manages were originally compiled into the
>   application or loaded from resource modules.

They're great to use for localization, as you can separate each language into different swf files.

> Resource modules can be a better approach to localization than
>   compile-time resources because you externalize the resource modules
>   that can be loaded at run time. This creates a smaller application SWF
>   file, but then requires that you load a separate SWF file for each
>   resource module that you use. The result can be an increased number of
>   network requests and an aggregate application size that is larger than
>   if you compiled the locale resources into the application. However, if
>   you have many locales, then loading them separately should save
>   resources in the long run.

Here's a link explaining resource modules:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f3c.html

My recommendation is to create the Resource Modules you need to use as localization as SWFs, and then either compile them into the application at compile time, or dynamically lead each ResourceModule at run-time, so you have access to it.

Comment: Thanks, but it means put resource files in one swf file. From some reason, I cannot go that way, I still need to load from resource files dynamically. Any suggestion?

Comment: Why don't you use resource modules? Edited my answer to explain.